# Como puedo hacer para que al seleccionar un medico con su horario establecido para la atencion me ponga en los SPAN dentro de un DIV?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

necesitaria ayuda con este problema que no lo se como seria, tengo horarios de atencion de MEDICOS por ejemplo MEDICO1 tiene el horario de atencion de 8 a 13 y 16 a 20 cada 15 minutos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
, estos se muestran en unos SPAN dentro de un DIV que dicen los horarios como en la imagen de abajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera que al seleccionar un medico y sus horarios de atencion me calcule y los ponga correlativamente en esos SPAN . por ejemplo si selecciono un MEDICO que tiene horario de 8 a 12 cada 15 minutos en los SPAN me deberia poner
8:00
8:15
8:30
8:45
9:00
y sucesivamente.

esto es posible?
les agradesco por su cooperacion y conocimiento.
GRACIAS

aqui tengo el codigo html domde aparecen los turnos.

Listado de Turnos

```
                          <!--CONTENEDOR TURNO MAÑANA-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-6">
                        <div class="card mb-1">
                            <div class="card-header bg-white text-center" id="tmanana"><i class="fas far fa-calendar-alt mr-1"></i><h5>Turno Mañana</h5></div>
                                
                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">8:00 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(1)" id="texto-1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button  class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(1)" disabled type="button" id="boton-1">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                     
                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">8:15 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(2)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-2" placeholder="">
                               <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(2)" disabled type="button" id="boton-2">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">8:30 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(3)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-3" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(3)" disabled type="button" id="boton-3">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">8:45 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(4)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-4" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(4)" disabled type="button" id="boton-4">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">9:00 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(5)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-5" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(5)" disabled type="button" id="boton-5">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">9:15 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(6)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-6" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(6)" disabled type="button" id="boton-6">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">9:30 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(7)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-7" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(7)" disabled type="button" id="boton-7">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">9:45 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(8)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-8" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(8)" disabled type="button" id="boton-8">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">10:00 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(9)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-9" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(9)" disabled type="button" id="boton-9">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">10:15 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(10)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-10" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(10)" disabled type="button" id="boton-10">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">10:30 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(11)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-11" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(11)" disabled type="button" id="boton-11">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">11:00 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(12)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-12" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(12)" disabled type="button" id="boton-12">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">11:15 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(13)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-13" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(13)" disabled type="button" id="boton-13">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">11:30 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(14)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-14" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(14)" disabled type="button" id="boton-14">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">11:45 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(15)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-15" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(15)" disabled type="button" id="boton-15">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">12:00 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(16)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-16" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(16)" disabled type="button" id="boton-16">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">13:00 a.m</span>
                                    <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(17)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-17" placeholder="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(17)" disabled type="button" id="boton-17">Editar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: La duda es si es posible??

Comment: éste seria el codigo html que tengo

Comment: lo que no me queda claro, es cual es el problema que tú tienes para implementar lo que has descrito?

Comment: Hola yussef....mi problema es que no encuentro cómo hacer esa operación, sería con javascript que tome los horarios del médico y en base a esos datos qué calcule el horario según cada 15 o 30 minutos o lo que salga en minutos ya predefinidos según el médico, me explico?

Comment: Entonces el problema es de sumar minutos???

Comment: exacto..!!! es sumar los minutos dependiendo de CADA y poniendo los horarios en los SPAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo, yo cree una estructura para guardar los bloques de horario, porque no sé cómo estas obteniendo eso

```js
const Horario = {
    dia: {
        inicio: 8,
        fin: 13
    },
    tarde: {
        inicio: 16,
        fin: 20
    },
    cada: 15,

};

var now = new Date();
var inicial = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), Horario.dia.inicio, 0, 0, 0);
var final  = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), Horario.dia.fin, 0, 0, 0);

for (var f = inicial; f <= final; f.setMinutes(f.getMinutes() + Horario.cada))
{
    let hora = ("0" + String(f.getHours())).slice(-2); //slice para dar formato de 2 digitos
    let minutos = ("0" + String(f.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
    console.log(hora + ":" + minutos );
}
```

Lo primero es obtener la fecha inicial y final.
Luego haces un for desde "inical" hasta "final", sumando los minutos que están declarado en la estructura en el campo "cada" y listo.

Luego haces lo mismo para la jornada de la tarde.

Para colocarlo dentro de un span, podrias colocar un id cada span: id="hora1", id="hora2", etc

Y luego pones:

```
 var now = new Date();
    var inicial = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), Horario.dia.inicio, 0, 0, 0);
    var final  = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), Horario.dia.fin, 0, 0, 0);

    let i=1;
    for (var f = inicial; f <= final; f.setMinutes(f.getMinutes() + Horario.cada))
    {
        let hora = ("0" + String(f.getHours())).slice(-2); //slice para dar formato de 2 digitos
        let minutos = ("0" + String(f.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
        document.getElementById("hora" + i).innerHTML = hora + ":" + minuto;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: La verdad....sos un genio y me ayudaste muchisimo, te agradezco por tu colaboración y tus conocimientos.GRACIAS.

Comment: ultima consulta !!! como hago para poner los resultados en los SPAN ?  <span class="input-group-text">8:00 a.m</span>

Comment: los resultados de los horarios los obtengo desde la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

éste sería el codigo HTML que tengo,me faltaría implementar lo demás

```
                    <div class="card mb-1">
                        <div class="card-header"><i class="fas fa-table mr-1"></i>Listado de Turnos</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                           
                         

                              <!--CONTENEDOR TURNO MAÑANA-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                            <div class="card mb-1">
                                <div class="card-header bg-white text-center" id="tmanana"><i class="fas far fa-calendar-alt mr-1"></i><h5>Turno Mañana</h5></div>
                                    
                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">8:00 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(1)" id="texto-1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button  class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(1)" disabled type="button" id="boton-1">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                         
                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">8:15 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(2)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-2" placeholder="">
                                   <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(2)" disabled type="button" id="boton-2">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">8:30 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(3)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-3" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(3)" disabled type="button" id="boton-3">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">8:45 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(4)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-4" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(4)" disabled type="button" id="boton-4">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">9:00 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(5)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-5" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(5)" disabled type="button" id="boton-5">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">9:15 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(6)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-6" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(6)" disabled type="button" id="boton-6">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">9:30 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(7)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-7" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(7)" disabled type="button" id="boton-7">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">9:45 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(8)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-8" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(8)" disabled type="button" id="boton-8">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">10:00 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(9)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-9" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(9)" disabled type="button" id="boton-9">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">10:15 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(10)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-10" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(10)" disabled type="button" id="boton-10">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">10:30 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(11)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-11" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(11)" disabled type="button" id="boton-11">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">11:00 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(12)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-12" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(12)" disabled type="button" id="boton-12">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">11:15 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(13)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-13" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(13)" disabled type="button" id="boton-13">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">11:30 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(14)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-14" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(14)" disabled type="button" id="boton-14">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">11:45 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(15)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-15" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(15)" disabled type="button" id="boton-15">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">12:00 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(16)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-16" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(16)" disabled type="button" id="boton-16">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">13:00 a.m</span>
                                        <input onclick="activareditarturnomtext(17)" type="text" class="form-control" id="texto-17" placeholder="">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="alerta(17)" disabled type="button" id="boton-17">Editar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                        
 </div>
```

Comment: Esto NO es una respuesta a la pregunta, para subir el codigo tienes que [edit] la pregunta, no responderla